# Phonegap Build app checking current wifi name in background

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm not sure how to tackle this, but I have a Phonegap Build app which I want to check what wifi network the phone is currently connected to.

I want it to be continually checking in the background, then if the phone connects to a specific network, the app will come to the foreground and open.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/) plugin to trigger events on network going `offline` and `online`. When the users changes network I believe the online event is trigger.

In the online event listener you can probably use [cordova-wifiscanner](https://github.com/nielsAD/cordova-wifiscanner) plugin to get the name of the wifi network.

> PS: I haven't tested or done this. But I believe this can work.

Comment: That's really useful, thanks, will this continue to check in the background though?

Comment: `network-information` will be on the background and it will emit offline and online events as the user switches between networks(I guess. Haven't tested). During these events you can use wifiscanner to get the name

Comment: Actually, when doing background fetches, app remembers previous connection type from app foreground. I'm trying to figure it out how to check connection when in background but currently no luck.